# How can I calculate division by negative number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I calculate division by negative numbers, for example $-213 \div 15$?

Comment: Isolate the negative sign, do ordinary division and place the - sign again.

Comment: What's your specific question? Is it with regard to the remainder left after division?

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{-x}{y}\equiv \frac{(-1)(x)}{y} \equiv (-1)\cdot \frac xy$$

so long as $y\neq 0$

Comment: and $y\neq 0$ should be!

Comment: Good point. Added

Answer (score 2):

Ak19's comment says it all.

Just remember that, if both terms have negative signs, they blow each other out and the reuslt is positive. So, in fraction notation:

$$\frac{6}{3} = 2$$
$$\frac{-6}{3} = -2$$
$$\frac{6}{-3} = -2$$
$$\frac{-6}{-3} = 2$$

Or, if you prefer: 
$$6:3 = 2$$
$$-6:3 = -2$$
$$6:-3 = -2$$
$$-6:-3 = 2$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$c=\frac ab\iff a=bc.$$